# Multiple Array list get in one array List in android

Tags: android

- My code using many array list with custom model, now i want to store all array list in one Seprate arrayList, how it is possible.

  ```
  public ArrayList<TwitterFeedCustomModel> mFacebookFeedCustomModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  public ArrayList<TwitterFeedCustomModel> mTwitterFeedCustomModelArrayList = new ArrayList<TwitterFeedCustomModel>();
  public ArrayList<LinkedInFeedCustomModel> mLinkedInFeedCustomModelArrayList = new ArrayList<LinkedInFeedCustomModel>();
  public ArrayList<InstagramFeedCustomModel> mInstagramFeedCustomModelArrayList = new ArrayList<InstagramFeedCustomModel>();
  public ArrayList<YouTubeFeedCustomModel> mYouTubeFeedCustomModelArrayList = new ArrayList<YouTubeFeedCustomModel>();
  public ArrayList<BlogFeedCustomModel> mBlogFeedCustomModelArrayList = new ArrayList<BlogFeedCustomModel>();
  ```
- All arraylist have seprate data, now i want to store all array list data in one arrayList, how we can do please help me.

Comment: How about using `generics` for creating the mother `ArrayList` ?

Comment: the types are different you can join them in an arraylist<fatherType> that all  these types extend that fatherClass. you cant achieve that without casting.

Comment: @AmirZiarati   please, can you explain with proper example.

Comment: Do you want to replace all this with a single list of use these ArrrayLists to produce a new list containing all?

Comment: the types will be casted and you wont be able to find the types easily after doing this !!!! you can use a list of objects like ArrayList<Object> and add all the lists into that.

Comment: @SPraveenKumar yes

Comment: are those lists the same size?

Comment: @pskink        all are different size

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Object> singleArrayList = new ArrayList<> ();
singleArrayList.add(mFacebookFeedCustomModelArrayList);
singleArrayList.add(mTwitterFeedCustomModelArrayList);
singleArrayList.add(mLinkedInFeedCustomModelArrayList);
......
```

while retrieving data you have to do type check.

Comment: after above implementation, how to get all data ?

Comment: `int index =0;  if( singleArrayList.get(index) instanceof ArrayList<TwitterFeedCustomModel>)      {  mFacebookFeedCustomModelArrayList = singleArrayList.get(index) ; ........} `like wise.

Comment: hi friend, your solution is correct, but i want to all arraylist data in one arraylist, on that single array list iwant to perform many operation like sorting, filter etc, so it is possible to without object, because this one is not help full for me

Comment: this one is doesn't meaning for implementation, because we check every time which object is, so same as my implementation,

Comment: ok.  ArrayList<Object> singleArrayList = new ArrayList<> ();   singleArrayList.addAll(mFacebookFeedCustomModelArrayList);

Comment: ok. ArrayList<Object> singleArrayList = new ArrayList<> (); singleArrayList.addAll(mFacebookFeedCustomModelArrayList);singleArrayList.add(mTwitterFeedCustomModelArrayList);
singleArrayList.add(mLinkedInFeedCustomModelArrayList);

Comment: Now. singleArrayList will contain elements of different arraylist not as diferent arraylist object. And you can use comparable or comparator to sort or filter data on it.

Comment: after implementation, i want to TwitterArraylist 2 item, facebook arraylist 3 item, how we get.

Comment: can you give me your email id ?

Comment: when i implement, above way get like this  CustomModel.FacebookFeedCustomModel@2007fad9 , not return element, return object

Comment: can you give me full example ?

Answer (score 0):

> Create a New class Say `NewT` that will be `super class` of
>   `TwitterFeedCustomModel`,
>   `LinkedInFeedCustomModel`,`InstagramFeedCustomModel`,`YouTubeFeedCustomModel`,`BlogFeedCustomModel`
>   and make new ArrayList of `NewT`(`newly created class`)